# How can I fix the convergence plot error on python (list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple)?

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def jacobi(A, b, x0, tol=1e-10, max_iter=100):
    n = len(A)
    x = x0.copy()
    res = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    for k in range(max_iter):
        x_new = np.zeros_like(x)
        for i in range(n):
            s = 0
            for j in range(n):
                if i != j:
                    s += A[i][j] * x[j]
            x_new[i] = (b[i] - s) / A[i][i]
            res[i].append(x_new[i])
        if np.linalg.norm(x_new - x) < tol:
            return x_new,res
        x = x_new.copy()
    return None,res

def gauss_seidel(A, b, x0, tol=1e-10, max_iter=100):
    n = len(A)
    x = x0.copy()
    res = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    for k in range(max_iter):
        for i in range(n):
            s = 0
            for j in range(n):
                if i != j:
                    s += A[i][j] * x[j]
            x[i] = (b[i] - s) / A[i][i]
            res[i].append(x[i])
        if np.linalg.norm(np.dot(A,x)-b) < tol:
            return x,res
    return None,res

A = np.random.normal(0, 1,size=(4,4)) + 10000 * np.identity(4)
b = np.random.normal(0, 1,size=(4,1))
x_exact=np.linalg.solve(A,b)
x0_jacobi = np.random.normal(0, 1,size=(4,1))
x0_gauss_seidel = np.random.normal(0, 1,size=(4,1))
x_jacobi,res_jacobi=jacobi(A,b,x0_jacobi)
x_gauss_seidel,res_gauss_seidel=gauss_seidel(A,b,x0_gauss_seidel)

plt.plot(range(len(res_jacobi[0])),[np.linalg.norm(x_exact-res_jacobi[:,k]) for k in range(len(res_jacobi[0]))],label='Jacobi')
plt.plot(range(len(res_gauss_seidel[0])),[np.linalg.norm(x_exact-res_gauss_seidel[:,k]) for k in range(len(res_gauss_seidel[0]))],label='Gauss-Seidel')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I'm solving the solution of Ax = b by Jacobi algorithm and Gauss-Siedel Alogorithm and plotting |x-xk|^2 for each k where x is the true solution.
In 46th and 47th line, I have error messages "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple".

Error Message: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.
So I tried to revise comma or parenthesis, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is :

`x_exact-res_jacobi[:,k]` you should do `x_exact-res_jacobi[:][k]`

`x_exact-res_gauss_seidel[:,k]` you should do `x_exact-res_gauss_seidel[:][k]`

```
plt.plot(range(len(res_jacobi[0])),[np.linalg.norm(x_exact-res_jacobi[:][k]) for k in range(len(res_jacobi[0]))],label='Jacobi')
plt.plot(range(len(res_gauss_seidel[0])),[np.linalg.norm(x_exact-res_gauss_seidel[:][k]) for k in range(len(res_gauss_seidel[0]))],label='Gauss-Seidel')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your Advice is very helpful!!! Enjoy your weekend~~

Comment: @CrustyCrab you welcome !! you too.